# How to Run the Nunit Testcases from the Spreadsheet Using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Let imagine i having spreadsheet, One column mentioned as Class name, Second column mentioned as NunitTestcases, thirds Column mentioned as Status(Yes or No)

My scenario is need to run testcases which are marked status as Yes.(For example i having 10 Testcases, i need to run only 4 Testcases) using Nunit.

Anyone can help me or sample code.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  You have 3 versions of C# listed, you should use only one tag.

Answer (score 0):

The question posted is not related to Selenium-Webdriver. You would like to invoke the methods based on reading an excel file. It is achievable though but have many con's. In order to achieve this, you should be able to read the excel sheet/file and check for the flag Status and if yes, you need to invoke the method using the reflection based on the class and method.

```
       string testAssemblyPath = "Assembly Path"; // Make sure only path and do not specify the assembly name.

        using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"ExcelFilePath.xlsx", FileMode.Open))
            {
                p.Load(stream);

                ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                int rowIndex = 2;

                for (int index = 0; index < ws.Dimension.Rows - 1; index++)
                {
                    if ("Yes" == ws.Cells[rowIndex + index, 3].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        string className = ws.Cells[rowIndex + index, 1].Value.ToString();
                        string methodName = ws.Cells[rowIndex + index, 2].Value.ToString();

                        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(testAssemblyPath + "TestAssembly.dll");
                        Type type = assembly.GetType(string.Concat(assembly.FullName.Split(',')[0], className));
                        if (type != null)
                        {
                            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
                            if (methodInfo != null)
                            {                                    
                                object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);

                                methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

The above code shows only on how we call a method, which is part of an test assembly (assuming the test methods are in test assembly). In order to read the excel I have used *[EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)*